# Every ergodic invariant measure of one dimensional dynamical system is a Dirac measure

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

Recently, I have learned some theorems about attractors and invariant measures. In the book I am reading, there is a theorem presented without its proof. I am interested in how to prove it.

Recall some definitions we will use below.
Let we have dynamical system $\{\varphi_{t},t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.  Then,

1. **Invariant measure $\mu$**: for any $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, $\mu(A)=\mu(\varphi_{t}^{-1}(A))$, $t\in\mathbb{R}.$
2. **Ergodic meausre $\mu$**: for any $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\varphi_{t}^{-1}(A)=A, t\in\mathbb{R}$, one has $\mu(A)=0$ or $1$.

The theorem whose proof I am interested in is as follows:

**Theorem** Consider the ODE $\dot{x}(t)=f(x(t))$, wit some $x(0)=x_0\in\mathbb{R},f\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ and let $\varphi_t$ be the associated dynamical system. If $\mu$ is an ergodic invariant measure of this dynamical system, then $\mu=\delta_{x_0}$, where $x_0$ is an equilibrium, i.e. $f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: Note that the flow of the specific example can be found explicitly by integration. But the only invariant sets are the zeros of $f$

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a connected component of the complementary of the set of equilibrium points. Then $U$ is an open interval, on which $f$ does not vanish.

The general theory of ordinary differential equations tells you that the restriction of $(\phi_t)_t$ to $U$ is conjugated to the translation flow on $\mathbb{R}$, which notoriously has no finite invariant measures, so neither does the flow on $U$.

Therefore, any finite invariant measure is supported on the set of equilibrium points, and the claims follows easily.

Comment: What do you mean with "the flow is conjugated with the translation flow on $\mathbb R$"?

Comment: That there exists a diffeomorphism $h$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $U$ such that for all $t,s$, $h(t+s)= \phi_s(h(t))$. In loose words, acting by the flow on $U$ is the same thing as acting on $\mathbb{R}$ by translations, up to a diffeomorphism.

Comment: But that's general to all (regular) flows no?

Comment: No, it’s not true for the translation flow on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.